# Writing a googlefinance wrapper

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google Sheet to track my stock portfolio. I use the `googlefinance` function to retrieve a stock price or last day change, but learned that it does not support all exchanges that I trade on.

I then thought to write a wrapper called simply `finance`, passing off the fetching of prices to Yahoo Finance in case the exchange isn't supported by Google. The wrapper would also give me the flexibility to make my sheet a bit more clean as well. For instance, Google and Yahoo use different indicators for stock exchanges. For instance, the Hong Kong Exchange is `HKG` on Google but `HK` on Yahoo. I would just like to type the exchange code that I use, and handle it in the wrapper. Here's an array with examples:

```
// exchange code that I use, that Google uses, Yahoo uses, exchange currency
[HKG, HKG,    HK,   HKD],
[TYO, TYO,    T,    JPY],
[TPX, TPE,    TW,   TWD],
[KRX, KRX,    KS,   KRW],
[FRA, FRA,    F,    EUR],
[NDQ, NASDAQ, null, USD],
[NSY, NYSE,   null, USD]
```

I later stepped off the idea of using an array, but just hardcode a switch statement, but still giving the array gives some background.

Now consider the following sheet and script:

```
   A    B     C
1  TYO  9984  =finance(A1, B1, "price")
2  NDQ  AAPL  =finance(A2, B2, "price")
3  NSY  GE    =finance(A3, B3, "price")
4  HKG  0865  =finance(A4, B4, "price")


function finance(exchange, ticker, type) {
    if (exchange == 'TYO') { // googlefinance() doesn't support TYO         
        return yahoofinance(ticker + '.T', type);
    }
    else {
        switch (exchange) {
          case 'HKG': return googlefinance('HKG:'    + ticker, type); break;
          case 'NDQ': return googlefinance('NASDAQ:' + ticker, type); break;
          case 'NSY': return googlefinance('NYSE:'   + ticker, type); break;
        }
    }
}

function yahoofinance(ticker, type) {
    return true; // implement later
}
```

I have 2 questions:

- I was expecting column `C` to fill with values, but instead get `googlefinance` is undefined. How can I solve this?
- `googlefinance` gets refreshed on the server each 2 mins (I believe). How can I make my own wrapper to refresh every 2 minutes (so also call `yahoofinance` every 2 mins) so that the cells are always updated with almost-realtime price information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues

**Issue 1:**

The code returns `undefined` because you are `returning` something `undefined`.
Here:

```
return googlefinance('HKG:'    + ticker, type)
```

`googlefinance` hasn't been defined anywhere in the script.

Your goal must be to `return` a `string` instead.

**Issue 2:**

- Another issue, is that you are using a custom formula to return another formula and expect the latter to evaluate. You can't execute a formula as a result of another formula.

**Modification 1:**

The switch statement overcomplicates the code and it does not add value.

You can replace it with a simple string concatenation `("a"+"b")` or more convenient with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
return `=googlefinance("${exchange}:${ticker}", "${type}")`;
```

this will return something in this format:

```
=googlefinance("NDQ:AAPL", "price")
```

but this will be a `text` in your sheet, it won't work as a formula.

**Modification 2:**

Change your approach. Instead of using a custom formula, use a regular google apps script function. You won't be able to use it as a custom formula then, but you can execute it in multiple ways, starting with a simple manual execution. Later, search other threads to see how you can execute that from custom menus or triggers.

### Solution - Regular Function approach:

```
function regularFinance() {
  
  const type = "price";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // put the name of your sheet
  const vals = sh.getRange('A1:B'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const formulas = [];
  
  vals.forEach(r=>{
     let dt = r[0]=='TYO'? yahoofinance(r[1], type):
            `=googlefinance("${r[0]}:${r[1]}", "${type}")`;             
     formulas.push([dt]);            
  })
  // paste data in column C
  sh.getRange(1,3,formulas.length,1).setValues(formulas);
  
  function yahoofinance(ticker, type) {
      return true; // implement later
  }

}
```

Like I said, this function is not a custom formula. It is a regular function which needs to be executed. One way to do that is to manually execute it from the script editor:

[image]

**Output:**

Make sure to correct the formulas. I am not familiar with what you want to achieve, so I will leave the formulas to you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, but how does it help me that it is returning a string? The formula in `C2` now is a string, and therefore not executed?

Comment: @Pr0no you can't return a formula with another formula and expect the second formula to evaluate. This can't happen. To make it more clear. Here you are using a custom function `finance` which returns another formula `googlefinance`. It is not possible to execute the second formula as a result of the first formula. The only way would be to use a regular function to construct such formulas. I will update my answer to see what I mean